# How to pass multiple column grouped result to a razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

When you group a list by multiple dates.

```
var groupedResult = myData.GroupBy(x => new { x.Date1, x.Date2 });
```

then i need to pass that result into the model of a razor view.
the debugger is telling me the type of groupedResult is as follows, with a being a anonymous

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<'a, MyDataViewModel>> groupedResult
```

but how should i pass this to my Razor view, i tried

```
@model IEnumerable<IGrouping<<DateTime, DateTime>, MyDataViewModel>
```

or

```
@model IEnumerable<IGrouping<new <DateTime, DateTime>, MyDataViewModel>
```

but no luck. i tried a few other syntaxes. but i don't seem to get the correct way to pass this model, when it was grouped on multiple results.

Comment: You should be creating a view model and projecting the results into that model `myData.GroupBy(x => new { x.Date1, x.Date2 }).Select(x => new YourViewModel { .... });` and then passing a collection of that view model to the view.

Comment: I think it's because it's an anonymous object made by `=> new { ... }`, that's what `IGrouping<'a, ...` is saying anyway

Answer (score 0):

I indeed created a viewmodel which i filled with a lynq query and i passed that model to the razor view

The model

```
public class GroupedPlanningViewModel
{
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StopDate { get; set; }
    public List<MyPlanningViewModel> Planning { get; set; }
}
```

Filling it in the controller

```
        var viewModel = from plan in myPlannings
            group plan by new
            {
                plan.StartBlock,
                plan.StopBlock
            }
            into f
            select new GroupedPlanningViewModel()
            {
                FromDate = f.Key.StartBlock,
                StopDate = f.Key.StopBlock,
                Planning = f.ToList()
            };
        return View(viewModel);
```

Then i added this as a model in the Razor view

```
@model IEnumerable<myProject.ViewModels.GroupedPlanningViewModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Tuple class, it can be like what you want.

```
var groupedResult = myData.GroupBy(x => Tuple.Create(x.Date1, x.Date2));
```

then you can receive it as below in razor view.

```
@model IEnumerable<IGrouping<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>, MyDataViewModel>
```

The group keys can be obtained as below.

```
<table>
@foreach (var d in @Model)
{
    <tr><th>@d.Key.Item1</th><th>@d.Key.Item2</th></tr>
}
</table>
```